Python Pandas loop cannot go beyond third loop
I have a dataframe df_esn:
       ESN01  ESN02       DATE  DFFAM  DFFB1  DFFB2
0      26019  26020 2018-02-21 -0.201 -0.265 -0.265
1      26019  26020 2018-02-21  0.604  0.139 -0.167
2      26019  26020 2018-02-24 -0.661 -0.163 -0.496

esn can be in column ESN01 or ESN02. When esn in ESN01, create a new column FF by copying DFFB1. If esn is in ESN02, create the new column FF by copying DFFB2. So the new dataframe will become:
       ESN01  ESN02       DATE  DFFAM  DFFB1  DFFB2       FF
0      26019  26020 2018-02-21 -0.201 -0.265 -0.265   -0.265
1      26019  26020 2018-02-21  0.604  0.139 -0.167    0.139
2      26019  26020 2018-02-24 -0.661 -0.163 -0.496   -0.163

This is done by:
df_esn['FF'] = df_esn.apply(lambda row: row['DFFB1'] if row['ESN01'] == esn \
                            else row['DFFB2'], axis=1)

Since there are many elements in esn contained in either ESN01 or ESN02, I used the following to list all:
esn_list = pd.unique(df[['ESN01','ESN02']].values.ravel())
by looping esn_list, to create the dataframe
for esn in esn_list:
    df_esn = df_esn[(df_esn['ESN01']==esn) | (df_esn['ESN02']==esn)]
    df_esn['FF'] = df_esn.apply(lambda row: row['DFFB1'] if row['ESN01'] == esn \
                                else row['DFFB2'], axis=1)

This can be achieved up to the second loop esn. From the third loop, it came with error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Users\118015\Python\Scripts\RR.py", line 71, in <module>
    df_esn['FF'] = df_esn.apply(lambda row: row['DFFB1'] if row['ESN01'] == esn \
  File "D:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3645, in __setitem__
    self._set_item_frame_value(key, value)
  File "D:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3775, in _set_item_frame_value
    raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
    

If just run the third loop esn alone, it is completed without any error message. How to make it loop without error message?

I can't reproduce. I'm getting -0.265, 0.139, -0.163 and -0.265, -0.167, -0.496 in df_esn['FF'].

what is esn in your example?

for esn in esn_list:
    df_esn = df_esn[(df_esn['ESN01']==esn) | (df_esn['ESN02']==esn)]
    df_esn['FF'] = df_esn.apply(lambda row: row['DFFB1'] if row['ESN01'] == esn \
                                else row['DFFB2'], axis=1)

I believe this loop is not working correctlly because of this line

df_esn = df_esn[(df_esn['ESN01']==esn) | (df_esn['ESN02']==esn)]

when you are running this line, in every iteration you are modifying your data 'df_esn' and filtering out all other rows except where you have esn in either 'ESN01' column or 'ESN02' column.
So as you iterate through your esn_list your data will keep getting smaller and smaller.

IIUC, you shouldn't use a loop for this operation, this is inefficient in pandas.
Either use np.select:
df_esn['FF'] = np.select(
    [df_esn['ESN01'].isin(esn_list), df_esn['ESN02'].isin(esn_list)],
    [df_esn['DFFB1'], df_esn['DFFB2']],
    np.nan)

Or, if you are sure that esn is either in ESN01 or ESN02, you could simplify it with np.where
df_esn['FF'] = df_esn['DFFB1'].where(df_esn['ESN01'].isin(esn_list), df_esn['DFFB2'])

Note that if you set esn_list = pd.unique(df_esn[['ESN01','ESN02']].values.ravel()), then the value is necessarily in ESN01, thus the code is equivalent to:
df_esn['FF'] = df_esn['DFFB1']

Output:
   ESN01  ESN02        DATE  DFFAM  DFFB1  DFFB2     FF
0  26019  26020  2018-02-21 -0.201 -0.265 -0.265 -0.265
1  26019  26020  2018-02-21  0.604  0.139 -0.167  0.139
2  26019  26020  2018-02-24 -0.661 -0.163 -0.496 -0.163

